# ANTLR4: Priority on ternary expression

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In the specification for the Jakarta Expression Language there is the following condition:

> Qualified functions with a namespace prefix have precedence over the
> operators. Thus the expression `${c?b:f()}` is illegal because `b:f()` is
> being parsed as a qualified function instead of part of a conditional
> expression. As usual, () can be used to make the precedence explicit,
> e.g `${c?b:(f())}`.

```
grammar ExpressionLanguageGrammar;
prog: compositeExpression;

compositeExpression: (dynamicExpression | deferredExpression | literalExpression)*;
dynamicExpression: DYNAMIC_START expression RCURL;
deferredExpression: DEFERRED_START expression RCURL;
literalExpression: literal;


literal: booleanLiteralExpression | floatingPointLiteralExpression | integerLiteralExpression | stringLiteralExpression | nullLiteralExpression;
booleanLiteralExpression: BOOL_LITERAL;
floatingPointLiteralExpression: FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL;
integerLiteralExpression: INTEGER_LITERAL;
stringLiteralExpression: StringLiteral;
nullLiteralExpression: NULL;

arguments: LPAREN expressionList? RPAREN;
expressionList: (expression ((COMMA expression)*));

lambdaParameters: IDENTIFIER | (LPAREN (IDENTIFIER ((COMMA IDENTIFIER)*))? RPAREN);

mapEntry: expression COLON expression;
mapEntries: mapEntry (COMMA mapEntry)*;

expression
    : expression (LBRACK expression RBRACK) #memberIndexExpression
    | expression bop=DOT (IDENTIFIER) #memberDotExpression
    | expression arguments #callExpression
    | prefix=(MINUS | NOT | EMPTY) expression #unaryExpression
    | expression bop=(MULT | DIV | MOD ) expression #infixExpression
    | expression bop=(PLUS | MINUS) expression #infixExpression
    | expression bop=(LE | GE | LT | GT) expression #relationalExpression
    | expression bop=INSTANCEOF IDENTIFIER #infixExpression
    | expression bop=(EQ | NE) expression #relationalExpression
    | expression bop=AND expression #logicalExpression
    | expression bop=OR expression #logicalExpression
    | IDENTIFIER (COLON IDENTIFIER)? arguments #namespaceFunctionExpression  
    | <assoc=right> expression bop=QUESTIONMARK expression bop=COLON expression #ternaryExpression
    | <assoc=right> expression bop=(ASSIGN | CONCAT) expression #assignExpression
    | lambdaParameters ARROW expression #lambdaExpression
    | expression SEMICOLON expression #semicolonExpression
    | IDENTIFIER #identifierExpression
    | literal #literalExpr
    | LBRACK expressionList? RBRACK  #listExpression
    | LCURL expressionList? RCURL #setExpression
    | LCURL mapEntries? RCURL #mapExpression
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN #parenExpression
    ;

// LEXER
LCURL: '{';
RCURL: '}';
BOOL_LITERAL: TRUE | FALSE;
TRUE: 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
NULL: 'null';
DOT: '.';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LBRACK: '[';
RBRACK: ']';
COLON: ':';
COMMA: ',';
SEMICOLON: ';';
GT: ('>' | 'gt');
LT: ('<' | 'lt');
GE: ('>=' | 'ge');
LE: ('<=' | 'le');
EQ: ('==' | 'eq');
NE: ('!=' | 'ne');
NOT: ('!' | 'not');
AND: ('&&' | 'and');
OR: ('||' | 'or');
EMPTY: 'empty';
INSTANCEOF: 'instanceof';
MULT: '*';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
QUESTIONMARK: '?';
DIV: ('/' | 'div');
MOD: ('%' | 'mod');
CONCAT: '+=';
ASSIGN: '=';
ARROW: '->';
DYNAMIC_START: DOLLAR LCURL;
DEFERRED_START: HASH LCURL;
DOLLAR: '$';
HASH: '#';
INTEGER_LITERAL: [0-9]+;
FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL: [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* EXPONENT? | '.' [0-9]+ EXPONENT? | [0-9]+ EXPONENT?;
fragment EXPONENT: ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? [0-9]+;

StringLiteral:                 ('"' DoubleStringCharacter* '"'
             |                  '\'' SingleStringCharacter* '\'') ;

fragment DoubleStringCharacter
    : ~["\\\r\n]
    | '\\' EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment SingleStringCharacter
    : ~['\\\r\n]
    | '\\' EscapeSequence
    ;
fragment EscapeSequence
    : CharacterEscapeSequence
    | '0'
    | HexEscapeSequence
    | UnicodeEscapeSequence
    | ExtendedUnicodeEscapeSequence
    ;
fragment CharacterEscapeSequence
    : SingleEscapeCharacter
    | NonEscapeCharacter
    ;
fragment HexEscapeSequence
    : 'x' HexDigit HexDigit
    ;

fragment UnicodeEscapeSequence
    : 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    | 'u' '{' HexDigit HexDigit+ '}'
    ;
fragment ExtendedUnicodeEscapeSequence
    : 'u' '{' HexDigit+ '}'
    ;
fragment SingleEscapeCharacter
    : ['"\\bfnrtv]
    ;

fragment NonEscapeCharacter
    : ~['"\\bfnrtv0-9xu\r\n]
    ;
fragment EscapeCharacter
    : SingleEscapeCharacter
    | [0-9]
    | [xu]
    ;
fragment HexDigit
    : [_0-9a-fA-F]
    ;
fragment DecimalIntegerLiteral
    : '0'
    | [1-9] [0-9_]*
    ;
fragment ExponentPart
    : [eE] [+-]? [0-9_]+
    ;
fragment IdentifierPart
    : IdentifierStart
    | [\p{Mn}]
    | [\p{Nd}]
    | [\p{Pc}]
    | '\u200C'
    | '\u200D'
    ;
fragment IdentifierStart
    : [\p{L}]
    | [$_]
    | '\\' UnicodeEscapeSequence
    ;

IDENTIFIER: LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;

LETTER:  '\u0024' |
                 '\u0041'..'\u005a' |
                 '\u005f' |
                 '\u0061'..'\u007a' |
                 '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' |
                 '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' |
                 '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' |
                 '\u0100'..'\u1fff' |
                 '\u3040'..'\u318f' |
                 '\u3300'..'\u337f' |
                 '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' |
                 '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' |
                 '\uf900'..'\ufaff';
DIGIT: '\u0030'..'\u0039'|
               '\u0660'..'\u0669'|
               '\u06f0'..'\u06f9'|
               '\u0966'..'\u096f'|
               '\u09e6'..'\u09ef'|
               '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f'|
               '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef'|
               '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f'|
               '\u0be7'..'\u0bef'|
               '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f'|
               '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef'|
               '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f'|
               '\u0e50'..'\u0e59'|
               '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9'|
               '\u1040'..'\u1049';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

ANY: .;
```

How can I turn this into a grammar error? Currently, this is parsed and does not return any errors. Should the errors be handled in the code-side or can it be done in the parser-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

I added a parser rule:

```
qualifiedFunction: IDENTIFIER COLON IDENTIFIER arguments;
```

Then I made it the first alternative of the `expression` rule:

```
expression
    : qualifiedFunction # QFunc
```

Then I modified the alternative for `ternaryExpression` to create two alternatives (order is important):

```
    | expression QUESTIONMARK qualifiedFunction  # badTernaryExpression
    | expression QUESTIONMARK  (trueExpr=expression COLON falseExpr=expression) # ternaryExpression
```

A useful "trick" you can use in ANTLR is to write a rule to recognize a particular invalid construct, and have ANTLR build a tree for you that makes it easy for you to identify.

This was the only way I could get ANTLR to recognize this and create a parse tree you can use to identify the invalid usage (I also, don't really understand why the parentheses are required in the `ternaryExpression`, but if I remove them, it recognizes your example as a regular ternary expression.

Now I can create a Listener:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRErrorStrategy;

public class BadTernaryListener extends ExpressionLanguageGrammarBaseListener {

    @Override
    public void enterBadTernaryExpression(ExpressionLanguageGrammarParser.BadTernaryExpressionContext ctx) {
        // Add your error to your error list here
        System.out.println("You can't use a qualified Function here");
    }

}
```

In practice you'd have some error handler collecting errors from the parse, and you could pass it into the Listener so you could use the same error listener to add whatever message you want when you encounter this usage.

I'm not entirely sure that this will cover **ALL** of the qualified function precedence needs, but it does detect this situation.

Comment: I've updated the grammar. Unfortunately, my problem is that I need this specific case to be a grammar error, in other words, to throw an Exception when it found this "ambiguity"

Comment: With this change, you should recognize that construct (a namespacefunctionexpression in the “true” position of your ternary expression.  You can handle it as a semantic error and catch it in a listener that looks fir it on “enter ternary expression “ and add your own error message.  This has the added advantage that you can give a “good” error message. Trying to encode it in the grammar is likely to profit a very difficult-to-understand error message.

Comment: I don’t have time at the moment, but can update my answer later today with more details if you need

Comment: The change in order to affect precedence did not address your problem.  I’m pretty sure it just caused ANTLR to back up and try another alternative.  I worked with the problem some and have updated the answer to use an approach where you have ANTLR recognize the ambiguous construct and then follow up with a listener that adds listens for that construct and adds an error when encountered,

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that soonish